# simple get API not working Node express with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a project with node express and angular, where it seems no matter what I do I cant get the final product to properly make the get request. 
I have a unfinished project where the request works thought. I am really failing to see what is the difference between the 2 projects.

my server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const routes = require('./server/routes/routes');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/routes', routes);

app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'))
    });

const port = process.env.PORT || 4600;

app.listen(port, (req, res)=>{
console.log(`RUNNING on port ${port}`);
});
```

The console log also doesn't happen since the request results in an error

[image]

my route.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axious = require('axios');
const PostAPI = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    axious.get(`${PostAPI}/posts`).then(posts => {
        console.log(posts.data);

         res.status(200).json(posts.data);


     }).catch(error => {
     res.status(500).send(error);
     })
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am not getting any error on running the application or any path errors.
But I am also never getting the result of the API anymore...
I am not sure what is wrong here. 
A replica of my entire project is here on this github, so you can see the angular part of the project.

https://github.com/ana-acoss/Node-Express-and-Angular-
I am getting this only when I run my app
[image]

I have been trying and trying to find out what is the problem but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config is mapping a response handler to `/routes`, but then you are requesting `/posts`? I'm thinking you just need to change `routes` to `posts` and then you should hit your backend call.

```
app.use('/routes', routes);

app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'))
    });
```

Comment: It was this! Thank you so much, I can't believe I just didn't see it...